# Compress string in php and decompress in python

Tags: php, python, compression, gzip

I have the following code in PHP:

```
$text = gzcompress($text);
// send $text to a python server
```

Then in python I have the following code:

```
text = request.POST.get('text', '')
new_text = zlib.decompress(text)
```

But this fails because the decompress function needs bytes and I am passing it a string. Does anyone know how to decompress a string in python that was compressed in php?

PS: I am not particularly interested in a specific algorithm or function.

Comment: What library are you using to make the POST request in Python? There may be a way to ask it to give you the content as bytes instead of str.

Comment: I am compressing the string in php then sending it to python. The string in PHP looks like this: `x�+I-.]�`. When I try to decoded it in python I get this error: `{TypeError}a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`. In php I am using Goutte to make the request

Comment: Ok. In Python what are you using to receive the request?

Comment: I am using django and the request object is a `WSGIRequest`

Comment: Hmm, can't say I know much about django... Does `new_text = zlib.decompress(text.encode())` do anything?

Comment: I definitely think we're on the right track, if I do `text.encode()` I get `b'x\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbds\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd/\x0b\x03\xef\xbf\xbd\x18\xef\xbf\xbd\\\x00 \xef\xbf\xbd\x04\x02'` but if I do `zlib.decompress(text.encode())` I get this error `{error}Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186563/discussion-between-mihai-vinaga-and-kevin).