# Compress string in php and decompress in python using zlib

Tags: python, php, encoding, compression, zlib

I know this question has already been asked there: [Compress string in php and decompress in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54151487/compress-string-in-php-and-decompress-in-python)

But there was no answer provided (discussion in chat has been lost).

I want a PHP client to compress a string on its side, send it to the server as a string contained in a json, then I want to be able to decompress it on my side.

I tried with zlib :

```
$ php -a
Interactive shell

php > $msg = "abcdefghijk";
php > $compressed = gzcompress($msg);
php > echo "'".$compressed."'"
php > ;
'x�KLJNIMK�����c'


$ python3
Python 3.7.8 (heads/master-dirty:daa285d, Jul 28 2020, 20:00:50) 
[GCC 9.3.1 20200408 (Red Hat 9.3.1-2)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import zlib
>>> comp_msg=r'x�KLJNIMK�����c'
>>> msg = zlib.decompress(comp_msg.encode('utf-8'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
zlib.error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check
```

... but it does not work.
I guess this is a problem of string encoding, but using PHP's mb_convert_encoding($compressed, "UTF-8"); does not solve the problem.

I can not ask the creator of first occurence of this question by lack of reputation ...
Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Probably the window sizes differ, PHP and Python might use different default values. You can specify this value while decompressing: `zlib.decompress(data, wbits=MAX_WBITS, bufsize=DEF_BUF_SIZE)` and/or while compressing in PHP.

Comment: this value is explictly exposed in zlib python, but not in PHP's gzcompress:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gzcompress.php
Furthermore on this later page, in a comment, I found:
"gzipped strings include header/metadata you can use to determine if a string is gzipped or not , but since gzcompress does not include that I found myself needing a way to determine if a string was compressed or not."
This is coherent with my error msg: "incorrect header check"

Comment: `'x�KLJNIMK�����c'` looks like a string representation of the compressed bytes, rather than the bytes themselves.  Are you able to encode them as base64, and then decode the base64 in python before decompressing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. try to escape non-ASCII charaters in the string constant:

```
<?php
$msg = "abcdefghijk";
$compressed = gzcompress($msg);
echo "'".addcslashes($compressed, "\x00..\x1F\\\'\"\x7F..\xFF")."'";
// outputs: 'x\234KLJNIMK\317\310\314\312\006\000\031\351\004c'
```

2. try to use `b` prefix to binary string literals in python:

```python
import zlib
comp_msg=b'x\234KLJNIMK\317\310\314\312\006\000\031\351\004c';
msg = zlib.decompress(comp_msg)
print(msg)
# prints: b`abcdefghijk`
```

Comment: Perfect !
Thanks a lot.